# SQL - (Update, From) statement with inner join on the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I have the below SQL query, the purpose of this query to detect a missing sequence: for example if I have seq 1,2,3,5... it should update the record 5 with a message "Previous sequence is missing".

Am trying to do this logic using update from `inner join` statement as follows, although its giving error on line 1 that `TblA` is ambiguous:

```
update      dbo.TblA 
set         Msg = 'Previous sequence is missing'
from        dbo.TblA R1
left join   dbo.TblA R2 
on          (R2.Sequence = R1.Sequence -1) 
and         (R2.StatementNumber = R1.StatementNumber)
where       R2.TransID is  null and R1.Sequence <> 1
```

I know that this can be easy fixed by nested queries but am thinking of something more organized and neat :)

Comment: Why isn't a sub-query "organised and neat"?

Comment: Use the alias you have defined : update R1 set Msg = 'Previous .... .... ...

Comment: @MarcGuillot this give "multi-part identifier" error

Comment: Ok, then use only an alias. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query. It doesn't set an alias on the table to update, just on the left join.

```
update      dbo.TblA 
set         Msg = 'Previous sequence is missing'
from        dbo.TblA 
left join   dbo.TblA R
on          (R.Sequence = TblA.Sequence -1) 
and         (R.StatementNumber = TlbA.StatementNumber)
where       R.TransID is  null and Tbla.Sequence <> 1
```

Comment: Although am not getting the logic why this is working... but its working fine... thanks a lot

Comment: Sufyan, as you said on a comment, you can't execute the update over an alias (multi-part identifier error). So we don't set two alias when joining TablA with itself, we only set an alias for the left join (which is not what we are updating).